# Node.js script listening keyboard events working only if the terminal running the script has focus on it

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, keyboard, keylogger

I'm creating a personal sort of keylog which will register the status of my keyboard (just "typing" or "not typing", nothing else).
The script is ready and working and it is the following:

```
var request = require('request');
var keypress = require('keypress');

keypress(process.stdin);

process.stdin.on('keypress', function (ch, key) {

    console.log("Mac user is typing...")       

    if (key && key.ctrl && key.name == 'c') {
        process.stdin.pause();
    }       

});

process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
process.stdin.resume();
```

My problem is the following.
The script works only if my focus is on the terminal used for running the script. If my focus switch to another app the script stops working.

How can I solve this problem?